# How can I read and obtain separated data from a file using 'fread' in C?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread, fseek

I've written in a file (using '**fwrite()**') the following:

```
TUS�ABQ���������������(A����������(A��B������(A��B���A��(A��B���A������B���A������0����A������0�ABQ�������0�ABQ�����LAS����������������A�����������A��&B�������A��&B��B���A��&B��B������&B��
B����153���B����153�LAS�����153�LAS�����LAX���������������:A����������:AUUB������:AUUB��B��:
AUUB��B����UUB��B����������B��������LAX���������LAX�����MDW���������������A����������A��(�������A��(����A��A��(����A������(����A����A�89���A����A�89MDW�����A�89MDW�����OAK���������
����������������������@�����������@�����������@�����������@�������������������������OAK���������OAK�����SAN���������������LA����������LA��P@������LA��P@��@A��LA��P@��@A������P@��@A����������@A��������SAN���������SAN�����TPA�ABQ����������������B�����������B��@�����...(continues)
```

which is translated to this:

```
TUSLWD2.103.47.775.1904.06.40.03AMBRFD4.63.228.935.0043.09.113.0ASDGHU5.226.47.78.3.26...(The same structure)
```

and the hexdump of that would be:

```
00000000  54 55 53 00 41 42 51 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TUS.ABQ.........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 28 41  00 00 0e 42 00 00 f8 41  |......(A...B...A|
00000020  00 00 00 00 4c 41 53 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....LAS.........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 88 41  00 00 26 42 9a 99 11 42  |.......A..&B...B|
(Continues...)
```

the structure is, always 2 words of 3 characters each one (i.e. TUS and LWD) followed by 7 floats, and then it repeats again on a on until end of file.

The key thing is: I just want to read every field separated like 'TUS', 'LWD', '2.10', '3.4', '7.77'...

And I can only use '**fread()**' to achieve that! For now, I'm trying this:

```
aux2 = 0;
fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);
fileSize = 0;
while (!feof(fp) && aux<=2) {
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char)*4, 1, fp);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char)*4, 1, fp);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        fread(&delay, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
        printf("%f", delay);
    }
    printf("\n");
    aux++;
    fseek(fp,sizeof(char)*7+sizeof(float)*7,SEEK_SET);
    aux2+=36;
}
```

And I get this result:

```
TUSABQ0.0000000.0000000.00000010.5000000.0000000.00000010.500000
AB0.0000000.000000-10384675421112248092159136000638976.0000000.0000000.000000-10384675421112248092159136000638976.0000000.000000
AB0.0000000.000000-10384675421112248092159136000638976.0000000.0000000.000000-10384675421112248092159136000638976.0000000.000000
```

But it does not works correctly...

*Note: forget the arguments of the last '**fseek()**', cos I've been trying too many meaningless things!
To write the words (i.e. TUS) into the file, I use this:

```
fwrite(x->data->key, 4, sizeof(char), fp);
```

and to write the floats, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    fwrite(&current->data->retrasos[i], sizeof(float), sizeof(float), fp);
}
```

Comment: "*words of 3 characters*": Why `...*4 ...`. It should be `fread(buffer, sizeof(char)*3 ...` or even "nicer" `fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 3, ...`

Comment: cos when I stored them in the file, each one has an ending '\0' character, so I'm trying to read it back @alk

Comment: From the dump you show (`TUSABQ...`) it looks as if the trailing `\0'` isn't written to the file. Perhaps show us a *clean* hex-dump of the files produces by an appropriate dumping tool like `hexdump`.

Comment: Ok, so you might also want to show the code you use to write the file.

Comment: For the sake of debugging make this `printf("%s", buffer);` line based: `printf("%s\n", buffer);` or indicate each block read like this `printf("'%s'", buffer);`

Comment: And this `sizeof(char)*7` does not follow any logic. It should either be `6` or `8`, depending on whether the `'\0'` had been written for each string or not.

Comment: read the "*Note" before write this last comment @alk , I tried too many things, then I started just trying nonsenses things

Comment: now you can see how I store them @alk

Comment: @wj127: Could you show the output of `hexdump -C file`? It shows the actual binary contents of the file, in hexadecimals; this is what alk already asked in the third comment above. You really have **two** problems: you didn't write the data correctly, and you are not reading it correctly. We can only fix the latter if we can see the actual data stored. Or, if you want, we can help you with both writing and reading the data, but then you'd need to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: ok, I'm gonna show what you've said me! give some minuts @Nominal Animal

Comment: @wj127: Based on the two `write()` lines you showed, you stored each `key` using 4 chars; each `float` should be stored in the file, but followed by `(sizeof (float) - 1)*sizeof (float)` chars of garbage data. You should have used `fwrite(&current..., sizeof (float), 1, fp)` instead (the count being `1` and not `sizeof (float)`).

Comment: ok @Nominal Animal , I've shown I think the __hexdump -C file__ ! And I've changed what you've said me in the code, but nothing....

Comment: @Nominal Animal: is it ok now? or should I show more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a structure to hold each data unit:

```
typedef struct {
    float  value[7];
    char   word1[5];  /* 4 + '\0' */
    char   word2[5];  /* 4 + '\0' */
} unit;
```

To make the file format portable, you need a function that packs and unpacks the above structure to/from a 36-byte array. On Intel and AMD architectures, `float` corresponds to IEEE-754-2008 [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) format in little-endian byte order. For example,

```
#define STORAGE_UNIT (4+4+7*4)

#if defined(__i386) || defined(_M_IX86) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64)

size_t unit_pack(char *target, const size_t target_len, const unit *source)
{
    size_t i;

    if (!target || target_len < STORAGE_UNIT || !source) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(target + 0, source->word1, 4);
    memcpy(target + 4, source->word2, 4);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        memcpy(target + 8 + 4*i, &(source->value[i]), 4);

    return STORAGE_UNIT;
}

size_t unit_unpack(unit *target, const char *source, const size_t source_len)
{
    size_t i;

    if (!target || !source || source_len < STORAGE_UNIT) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(target->word1, source, 4);
    target->word1[4] = '\0';

    memcpy(target->word2, source + 4, 4);
    target->word2[4] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        memcpy(&(target->value[i]), source + 8 + i*4, 4);

    return STORAGE_UNIT;
}

#else
#error Unsupported architecture!
#endif
```

The above only works on Intel and AMD machines, but it is certainly easy to extend to other architectures if necessary. (Almost all machines currently use IEEE 754-2008 binary32 for `float`, only the byte order varies. Those that do not, typically have C extensions that do the conversion to/from their internal formats.)

Using the above, you can -- should! must! -- document your file format, for example as follows:

```
Words are 4 bytes encoded in UTF-8
Floats are IEEE 754-2008 binary32 values in little-endian byte order

A file contains one or more units. Each unit comprises of

    Name    Description
    word1   First word
    word2   Second word
    value0  First float
    value1  Second float
    value2  Third float
    value3  Fourth float
    value4  Fifth float
    value5  Sixth float
    value6  Second float

There is no padding.
```

To write an unit, use a `char` array of size `STORAGE_UNIT` as a cache, and write that. So, if you have `unit *one`, you can write it to `FILE *out` using

```
    char  buffer[STORAGE_UNIT];

    if (unit_pack(buffer, sizeof buffer, one)) {
        /* Error! Abort program! */
    }
    if (fwrite(buffer, STORAGE_UNIT, 1, out) != 1) {
        /* Write error! Abort program! */
    }
```

Correspondingly, reading from `FILE *in` would be

```
    char buffer[STORAGE_UNIT];

    if (fread(buffer, STORAGE_UNIT, 1, in) != 1) {
        /* End of file, or read error.
           Check feof(in) or/and ferror(in). */
    }
    if (unit_unpack(one, buffer, STORAGE_UNIT)) {
        /* Error! Abort program! */
    }
```

If `one` is an array of `unit`s, and you are writing or reading `one[k]`, use `&(one[k])` (or equivalently `one + k`) instead of `one`.

Comment: yeah, it worked! it took me a while to understand it, but finally I got it! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @wj127: Good to hear! Yes, I'm .. overly verbose; wall of text and all.. BTW, there is an additional reason why using such a buffer is a good idea, and that is *alignment requirements*. Depending on the hardware architecture, certain types like `float` cannot just reside at *any* address, but require the address to be a multiple of some small number, so that the processor can correctly access it. (Alternatively, unaligned accesses may just be very slow.) Using a buffer like this lets you pack your data in the file format safely, without worrying about such alignment or padding.

Comment: no no, it's ok! in fact, this question of mine was about a practical I'm doing for '__Operating Systems__' subject, so it's nice to learn more free info about it, and seems like you know a lot about this matter! Thanks, again! :)